# How can add one insert into update if not exists cid_cod

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE cid_unidade SET tp_agravo = 1
WHERE co_cid in('Y00', 'Y000', 'Y001', 'Y002' , 'Y003', 'Y004' , 'Y005', 'Y006', 'Y007',
'Y008', 'Y009', 'Y01', 'Y010', 'Y011', 'Y012', 'Y013', 'Y014', 'Y015', 
'Y016', 'Y017', 'Y018', 'Y019', 'Y02', 'Y020', 'Y021', 'Y022', 'Y023', 
'Y024', 'Y025', 'Y026', 'Y027', 'Y028', 'Y029', 'Y03', 'Y030', 'Y031', 
'Y032', 'Y033', 'Y034', 'Y035', 'Y036', 'Y037', 'Y038', 'Y039', 'Y04', 
'Y040', 'Y041', 'Y042', 'Y043', 'Y044', 'Y045', 'Y046', 'Y047', 'Y048', 
'Y049', 'Y05', 'Y050', 'Y051', 'Y052', 'Y053', 'Y054', 'Y055', 'Y056', 
'Y057', 'Y058', 'Y059', 'Y06', 'Y060', 'Y061', 'Y062', 'Y063', 'Y064', 
'Y065', 'Y066', 'Y067',  'Y068',  'Y069',  'Y07',  'Y070',  'Y071',  'Y072', 
'Y073',  'Y074',  'Y075',  'Y076',  'Y077',  'Y078',  'Y079',  'Y08',  'Y080', 
'Y081',  'Y082',  'Y083',  'Y084',  'Y085',  'Y086',  'Y087',  'Y088',  'Y089', 
'R456',  'T742')

IF NOT EXISTS INSERT
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `merge` command in sql server:

```
merge cid_unidade trg
using (
   select * from (values 
   ('Y00'), ('Y000'), ('Y001'), ...,  ('T742')) t(co_cid)
) src 
on src.co_cid = trg.co_cid
when matched then 
   update set tp_agravo = 1
when not matched then
   insert (co_cid, cid_unidade) values (src.co_cid , 1)
```